# How to get Excel Columns Range in Epplus and set its Column Width?

Tags: epplus

Example. How in Epplus?

```
Sheet.Cells["a1:d1"].Column.Width = 10;
```

In Excel Interop:

```
Sheet.get_Range("a1", "d1").ColumnWidth = 10;
```

Answer (score 6):

You can set the widths but have to do it per column.  You can do it over a range like this:

```
for (int c = 1; c <= ws.Cells["A1:D1"].Columns; c++)
    ws.Column(c).Width = 10;
```

If you want to do it on ALL cells with data you can omit the range and Epplus will only return cells with actual data in it:

```
for (int c = 1; c <= ws.Cells.Columns; c++)
    ws.Column(c).Width = 10;
```

Comment: Thanks Master Ernie :)

Comment: @ECoder  No problem.  Just remember to make the question as answered to close it out (and you get point).  Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: @ECoder If you get the answer, you may want to mark it as `Answer` (click on the `check mark`). It will help other readers of the post.

Comment: Thanks @ErnieS you saved my time and efforts

Answer (score 2):

And this to start in specific Column. Not Using ws.Cells[range]

```
 int startColumn = 3; int endColumn = 10;
 for (int a = startColumn; a <= endColumn; a++)
    {
       Sheet.Column(a).Width = 10;
    }
```